# program hangs before goToSleep();

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

Hi i have this program where it uses voice command to unlock the phone.

In this VoiceRecog activity, when i detected command is wrong, it will call goToSleep(1000); which locks the device.

However, the program will hang before it goes to sleep. What could be the problem? What should i put for the int value in the method?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

       if(command ==right)
           ....
       else
           pm.goToSleep(10);
}
```

I have tried using

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
```

but the program still hangs before it locks.

Answer (score 1):

Only app signed as system app can call goToSleep(), not yours. And at least now, I don't see any good way to force the device to sleep.

Comment: because i have disableKeyguard(); when i pressed the power button, and a voice recognition program is called. 

The user will say the correct command the phone, so if a wrong command is heard, i will have to lock back the phone.

Comment: In sdk documentation, I see some comments on calling locknow():
"The calling device admin must have requested USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK to be able to call this method; if it has not, a security exception will be thrown. "
"To control this policy, the device admin must have a "force-lock" tag in the "uses-policies" section of its meta-data. " Is this why you have such a problem?

Comment: I have installed a app widget to lock my phone easily, and this app requires the adimn feature.So, I am sure that the DevicePolicyManager can lock the phone. However, when it comes to "turn off the screen", I don't have any good idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply :) so if I declare USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK in the manifest file, I would not get the error before the phone locks?

Comment: just have a try. I am a green hand in android. Please let me know if it works.